# centering text in bootstrap button

Tags: css

Anyone knows why my text won't center? and how i can fix it? I tried using text-align:center but it still is not working.

```css
.btn-orange {
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin:1px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e3690b;
    border-color: #e3690b;
    padding: 20px 50px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-stretch: ultra-expanded;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn-orange" style="text-align:center !important;">Value<br> My Videos</button>
```

Comment: Your padding is the cause

Comment: because you have uneven padding. Your padding is 50px right and 10px left. Make those values match and the text will center.

Comment: Use padding: 20px 0 20px 0; /* Meaning padding: TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding: 20px 50px 10px 10px;`

top right bottom and left are not matching.

try  `padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvpLBJ

You had unequal padding which caused the text to move in weird ways.
What I did was remove a bunch of properties and add padding: 20px 20px; which creates equal padding (meaning spacing inside the button) on all sides (top, right, bottom, left). You can declare padding in a couple of ways:

`padding: 20px; since its equal on all sides,`

`padding: 20px 20px; the first 20px applies to top and bottom and the second 20px to right and left`

`padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; this goes in the direction of a clock, meaning top, right, bottom, left,`

`padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px;`

All of those will do the same thing, the only difference will be in code length.